# What is the opposite of a continued fraction?

Tags: real-analysis

Is it true that $-[a_1,a_2,...,a_n]=[-a_1,-a_2,...,-a_n]$ for $[a_1,a_2,...,a_n]$ a continued fraction?

If that is the case, is there an easy way to see it (until now I only tried with induction but it doesn't look very good...)?

Thanks!

Comment: I mean it looks ok, I was just wondering if it's even easier to see...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Induct on $n$, using
$$[a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n] = a_1 +\frac{1}{[a_2,\ldots,a_n]}$$